# Kill subprocess started by imported module

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a `call_script.py`:

```
def call():
    pro = subprocess.Popen(['make_batches.py'])
    with open('call.pid', 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(pro.pid))
    file.close()
    pro.wait()

def main():
    call()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and a  `main_script.py`:

```
import call_script
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    call.main()
    path = Path.cwd()
    pid = path.glob('**/call.pid')
    if criteria_met:
         #KILL PROCESS

main()
```

The `call_script.py` is producing batches every 5 min and so I need to wait for those but once `criteria_met` is True in `main_script.py` I would like to kill the process defined in `call.pid`, however `main_script.py` will not continue past `call.main()` since it's waiting

Comment: Why not just do the whole thing in one process?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call pro.wait in a nonblock way. Try with pro.wait(timeout=1) or some timeout suits you. Then check in a upper loop wait for 'criteria_met' or the subprocess.TimeoutExpired exception for normal exit.